# Pegar dados de formulários HTML - TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Eu tenho uma API-web, em c#, que guarda no banco dados recebidos via Post, e estou tentando fazer uma interface em Angular, que tem um formulário HTML, que deve receber o título e o corpo dos dados.

Este é o HTML, componentizado:

```
    <div>
  <form method="POST" id="push">

    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"  id="title"/>
    
    <input type="text" name="body" placeholder="Body" id="body"/>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="getData()"/>
    </form> 
  
</div>
```

Este é o arquivo Typescript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

function getData()
{
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    var body = document.getElementById("body");

  alert(title); //Essa linha é só para testar se consegui pegar os dados do form
}
```

O problema é que, quando clico em "Submit", recebo um 404 na tela. Por que isso acontece? Sou nova em Angular.

Comment: Já fez algum curso de **Angular**, já leu e soube como interpretar a documentação? Não é com `document.getElementById` que se pega valores de um form com Angular, ainda mais se for pra enviar esses dados para uma API. Aconselho ver a documentação, realizar algum curso **`(youtube tem alguns grátis)`** para assimilar pelo menos o básico do framework, senão irá ficar batendo cabeça desnecessariamente!

Comment: Ja fiz uns três cursos diferentes de Angular com typescript. Na documentação ta explicado tudo certinho? Obrigado pela dica! :)

Comment: É o que o LeAndrade falou, você não deve usar o document.getElementById com Angular. Para você fazer o envio e recebimento de dados do seu arquivo.ts para o arquivo.html você usa o Bind: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax  Outra coisa se você quer enviar dados para uma API use um service: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services .  O Angular não trabalha diretamente com o DOM, portanto você terá problema ao tentar manipular os dados diretamente no DOM. Leia: https://angular.io/guide/elements Porém sugiro que você se aprofunde mais no Framework.